# Check if element is hidden in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I can do

```
if( !Ext.getCmp('myElem'))
```

to check whether the element exist and

```
Ext.getCmp('myElem').hide();
```

or

```
Ext.getCmp('myElem').show();
```

to hide or show the element.

But, how to check if the element is hidden?

```
if (Ext.getCmp('myElem') && <*hidden*>){//???
     //do something
}
```

Browsing SO didn't help me to find an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`isVisible()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-isVisible):

> Returns true if this component is visible.

Comment: I've got an error: console.log(Ext.getCmp('myElem').isVisible());//Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isVisible'

Comment: Yes, it is rendered. Also, the object is seen in the console.

Comment: I don't know why but in my example console.log(Ext.getCmp('BellPanel')._hidden); works (I went through the object properties in the console). I have no idea now why .isVisible() doesn't work.

Comment: create a jsfiddle with your example.

Comment: Sorry I can't use jsfiddle now. 
I'm closing this question as solved (as you helped me to find a solution). Thank you.